# NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle Driving me insane

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a currency calculator to work, and I've stumbled accross a problem I do not know how to solve.

The problem is that when I normally type into the textfield I can obviously type over the 100.20, the problem arises when I try to do this using buttons.

Whole numbers work fine but as soon as I click on the dot button it put's the dot after the 100.20 so I end up with 100.20. and whatever I click after it.

If I don't use NSNumberFormatter it works fine as well.

Here are the code snippets :

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
{
    mainNumber = 100.20;
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    mainField.stringValue = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: mainNumber]];
}

if(!userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal)
{
    userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = YES;
    mainField.stringValue= [mainField.stringValue stringByAppendingString:@"."];
}
```

Comment: What method is that if statement in? You pasted it without any context.

Comment: - (IBAction)buttonDotPressed: (id)sender
    {
    if(!userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal)
    {
    userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = YES;
    mainField.stringValue= [mainField.stringValue stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
    }